# Accessing static members from 2 inherited class

Tags: c++, inheritance, multiple-inheritance, static-members

I have a base class with a static queue:

```
class A : public otherClass{
protected:
    static Queue queue[SIZE];
    static int front, rear;
public:
    void funcA();
    void funcB();
 };
```

Now 2 classes inherit this class:

```
class B: public A{
public:
     void funcC();
}

class C: public A{
public: 
    void funcD();
}
```

My question is, when I instantiate class B and C, will there be 1 instance of the queue and both B and C pointing to it, or will there be  seperate instance for B and C ?

Answer (score 1):

The queue is static -- There is only one instance of it *in the whole program* no matter how many subclasses or instances of A you create.

As far as memory layout is concerned, a static member is no different than a global variable declared outside any class (save for name mangling).

Answer (score 0):

A static variable is independent of the instances of the class. Static variables are instantiated on initialization and they are destroyed on exiting the program. Hence, their lifetime is equal to the lifetime of the program.